# Running CasperJS from R on Ubuntu via Scheduled Tasks

Tags: r, cron, casperjs

I have an R script that runs CasperJS through a "system" command and is scheduled through the "Scheduled Tasks" program on Ubuntu. If I hit the "Run selected task" button in Scheduled Tasks, the rscript runs as expected and produces the expected output. However, if I let it run as scheduled, I get an error complaining that phantomjs isn't installed properly. This leads me to believe there is a problem with environment variables during the cron job.

I've tried to resolve this with:

```
debug <- system(paste0("cd /home/tony/casperjs/bin/; PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/share/phantomjs/bin; casperjs /home/tony/rscripts/launch/casper/script.js"))
```

However, still fails when I let it run on its schedule.

UPDATE:
The specific error I'm getting is:

```
Fatal: [Errno 13] Permission denied; did you install phantomjs?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was missing the "phantomjs" file as part of the executable string. I ended up using:

```
Sys.setenv(PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE="/usr/local/share/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs")
```

And that solved my issue.